# Precompiled header gives stray 216 error

Tags: c++, gcc, precompiled-headers

When I precompile header with gcc 4.6.1 and then try to use it I'm getting error stray '\216'. During compilation there wasn't any errors so what's the story?

Answer (score 1):

How do you use it?

Your `#include` should not change, mentioning the original header file, like `#include "header.h"`

But your directory should contain both `header.h` and  `header.h.gch` and of course the source file `foo.cc` or `bar.c` which has `#include "header.h"`

Comment: Probably the OP tried to use `#include "header.h.gch"`.  Since a gcc precompiled header is a binary file, a stray `'\216'` is a likely symptom.  (I just tried it and got a veritable blortload of such errors.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, indeed I've tried to do that. In code::blocks in build options in compiler tab in other option tab I've added -include "header.h.gch". I suppose I should just add "header.h" is that so?

Comment: I haven't used code::blocks, and I don't know what `-include` does.  I'm saying you should have `#include "header.h"` (*not* `#include "header.h.gch"`) in your source file.  Whether you need to do something else to tell your IDE about it is another question.